# How do I find each instance of a model in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to iterate through each instance of a model I have defined.

Say I have the following in `models.py`, under the `people` django app:

```py
class foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, default="No Name")
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

And I have populated the database to have the following data in foo:

1. name="Charley", age=17
2. name="Matthew", age=63
3. name="John", age=34

Now I want to work out the average age of my dataset. In another part of the program (outside the `people` app, inside the `project` folder), in a file called `bar.py` that will be set up to run automatically every day at a specific time, I calculate this average.

```py
from people.models import foo
def findAverageAge():
    total = 0
    for instance in //What goes here?// :
        total += instance.age
    length = //What goes here, to find the number of instances?//
    average = total / length
    return average
print(findAverageAge)
```

In the code above, the //What goes here?// signifies I don't know what goes there and need help.

Comment: I guess you did not take the [tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#playing-with-the-api).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can retrieve all elements with [**`.all()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#all):

```
from people.models import foo

def findAverageAge():
    total = 0
    qs = foo.objects.all()
    for instance in :
        total += instance.age
    length = len(qs)
    average = total / length
    return average

print(findAverageAge())
```

But you should *not* calculate the average at the Django/Python level. This requires retrieving *all* records, and this can be quite large. A database itself can calculate the average, and this is (normally) done in a more efficient way. You can [**`.aggregate(…)`** [jango-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate) on the queryset with:

```
from people.models import foo

def findAverageAge():
    return foo.objects.aggregate(
        avg_age=Avg('age')
    )['avg_age'] or 0

print(findAverageAge())
```

You should make a [*management command*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/) however: this will load the Django apps, and also makes it more convenient to run command with parameters, etc.

Comment: Agree, looping is expensive